# How to drag and drop using jQuery (kendo)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, telerik

I am trying to achieve the same functionality as in fitbit.com. When the user drags and drops a div, the divs move and give space to the new div.

[image]

My div structure is below:

```
<div class="k-content" style="min-height: 800px; position: relative;">
                    <div style="position: relative;min-height: 800px;" id="cont">
                        <div id="Steps" style="height: 240px;" class="chartContainer"></div>
                        <div id="Distance" style="height: 240px;" class="chartContainer"></div>
                        <div id="Floors" style="height: 240px;" class="chartContainer"></div>
                        <div id="ActivityMinutes" style="height: 240px;" class="chartContainer"></div>

                        <div id="Calories" style="height: 240px;" class="chartContainer"></div>
                        <div id="Weights" style="height: 240px;" class="chartContainer"></div>
                        <div id="BMI" style="height: 240px;" class="chartContainer"></div>
                        <div id="Sleep" style="height: 240px;" class="chartContainer"></div>

                        <div id="Food" style="height: 240px;" class="chartContainer"></div>
                        <div id="Water" style="height: 240px;" class="chartContainer"></div>
                        <div id="Div3" style="height: 240px;" class="chartContainer"></div>
                        <div id="Div4" style="height: 240px;" class="chartContainer"></div>
                    </div>
```

My code for drag and drop is below:

```
 $(".chartContainer").kendoDraggable({
    hint: function (element) {
        return element.clone();
    },
    container: $("#cont"),

    dragstart: function (e) {
        e.currentTarget.hide();
    },
    dragend: function (e) {
        e.currentTarget.show();
    }
});


$("#cont").kendoDropTarget({

    drop: function (e) {
        e.draggable.destroy(); 
        // what to do next?

    }

});
```

I can drag it to the place where I want to drop, How do I drop it to the new location?, suppose between two divs?

http://jsfiddle.net/ar2t3/4/

Comment: How are your elements laid out? If simply floated you just need to insert it in the correct position (before/after the item under the cursor). If absolute coordinates, you will need to rearrange the other elements. Can you provide the full css etc for this page? Better yet, a JSFiddle that shows the whole problem.

Comment: There's a javascript error in your jsfiddle. Fix it.